# Dijsktra's algorithm using maps is not adding values correctly

Tags: c++, algorithm, maps, dijkstra

I have created a function which uses maps for Dijkstra’s shortest path algorithm. I'm close to getting it to work correctly, but I am currently stuck. I know maps are not the most efficient, nor even normally used, and did it this way for a better understanding of maps. I believe I have mostly everything correct, but can't seem to iterate and write to the correct location in the distance vector. This is the code:

```
void Graph::dikAlgorithm(string start, string finish)
{
    nodeAmount = mapData.size();
    vector<double> costVec(nodeAmount);
    vector<bool> vis(nodeAmount);

    vector<map<string, double>> keys;
    for (auto& kv : mapData)
    {
        keys.push_back(kv.second);
    }

    int staIndex = distance(mapData.begin(), mapData.find(start));
    int finIndex = distance(mapData.begin(), mapData.find(finish));

    //initialize the distance vector to infinity
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeAmount; ++i)
    {
        costVec[i] = INFINITY;
        vis[i] = false;
    }

    //starting city distance is set to zero
    costVec[staIndex] = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < nodeAmount; ++i)
    {
        int cur = -1;
        for (int j = 0; j < nodeAmount; ++j)
        {
            //if visited node has been visted, continue incrementing j
            if (vis[j]) continue;

            //once an unvisted node has been reached, check to see if next is less than current
            if (cur == -1 || costVec[j] < costVec[cur])
            {
                cur = j;
            }
        }

        //set the visited node to solved
        vis[cur] = true;

        map<string, double>::iterator tempMap = keys[cur].begin();

        //add the total distance using maps and vectors
        for (int j = 0; j < keys[cur].size() - 1; j++)
        {
            double tempCost = tempMap->second;
            double pathCost = costVec[cur] + tempCost;
            if (pathCost < costVec[j])
            {
                costVec[distance(mapData.begin(), mapData.find(tempMap->first))] = pathCost;
            }
            tempMap++;
        }
    }
    double answer = costVec[finIndex];
    cout << "The least amount of money from " << start << " to " << finish << "    is " << answer << endl;
}
```

I believe the error is occuring after this line

```
     map<string, double>::iterator tempMap = keys[cur].begin();
```

This error is keeping the distance vector from being properly added. Because of this I usually end up with a random value from the map being the shortest path, or even infinity. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Feel free to ask me if you need any more details.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
map<string, double>::iterator tempMap;
tempMap = keys.begin();
```

instead of

```
map<string, double>::iterator tempMap = keys[cur].begin();
```

Comment: It threw an error saying there was no operator which matches these operands.  Do you mean you want it to iterate to a new key with each pass through the loop?